# Bibliography management

Tags: cross-referencing, bibliographystyle

I am using Latex for my synopsis
my documentclass is article
I used

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{ibrahim2017kumaraswamy}Ibrahim, M. (2017). The Kumaraswamy power function distribution. J. Stat. Appl. Probab, 6, 81-90.
\end{thebibliography}.
```

after running this it gives number like [1] in the start which is against university's formate
can anyone tell me how to remove this numbering from the bibiliography

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the scant information you've provided, I will assume that your university requires you to generate authoryear-style citation call-outs. If this assumption is correct, I suggest you (a) load the `natbib` citation management package and (b) use the optional argument of `\bibitem` to provide information needed by `natbib` in order to create citation call-outs using the `\citet` and `\citep` directives.

Incidentally, `Ibrahim` [would appear to be](https://dc.naturalspublishing.com/jsap/vol6/iss1/7/) the *given name* rather than the surname of the author of the bibliographic entry of interest. For the citation call-outs, be sure to provide information about the author's surname.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\citet{ibrahim2017kumaraswamy}, \citep{ibrahim2017kumaraswamy}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem[Abdul-Moniem(2017)]{ibrahim2017kumaraswamy}
  Abdul-Moniem, Ibrahim B. (2017). 
  The Kumaraswamy power function distribution. 
  J. Stat.\ Appl.\ Probab, 6, 81--90.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```